# upsize_ts column in legacy database - what does it mean?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

We have to work with legacy database and many tables have a column called `upsize_ts` of datatype `timestamp` not related to the data stored.

What is its purpose? Is this some sort of `rowversion` column? Can we delete that column?

Comment: Full-text indexing may use a `timestamp` column to manage incremental population.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found, that "upsize_ts" column is created when upgrading MS Access database to MSSQL using Upsizing wizard:

> Upsizing is the process of migrating some or all database objects from
>   a Microsoft Access database (.mdb) to a new or existing Microsoft SQL
>   Server database or new Microsoft Access project (.adp).

The upsize wizard documentation mentions following:

> Timestamp Columns 
>        By default, the Upsizing Wizard creates new columns with the data type of timestamp in SQL Server tables generated from Microsoft Access
>   tables that contain floating-point (single or double), Memo, or OLE
>   fields.

---

> Can we delete that column?

This field should not be deleted if database will still be used by MS Access (which is case for our app).

---

More About Upsizing Wizard:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/use-the-upsizing-wizard-HP005273009.aspx

Answer (score 3):

> Is this some sort of rowversion column?

Yes, it is. In versions of SQL Server before 2008, [`TIMESTAMP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) is the equivalent to [`ROWVERSION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

> Can we delete that column?

No one can answer that for you - you need to find out if it really is not used anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, but I was not talking about TIMESTAMP/ROWVERSION data type. I was concerned about "upsize_ts" field specifically and how/why it is in all tables in that DB when App is not requiring it. See my answer below.